# Can aria2c download list of urls with specific file names for each?

Tags: download, aria2

For example i have a list of URLs:

```
https://link.com/file/get/somefile.ext
https://go.com/download/anotherfile.ext
https://program.com/selection/download.php?id=26162
```

I want to set a specific name for last URL, something like this:

```
https://program.com/selection/download.php?id=26162 -o thirdfile.ext
```

Is it possible with aria2c download list syntax?

I know that I can do like this:

```
aria2c https://link.com/file/get/somefile.ext
aria2c https://go.com/download/anotherfile.ext
aria2c https://program.com/selection/download.php?id=26162 -o thirdfile.ext
```

But this way I run just too much of aria2c's. ._.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the documentation on [`--input-file=`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-i)

> Additionally, options can be specified after each URI line. Option lines must start with one or more white space characters (`SPACE` or `TAB`) and must only contain one option per line. … See the [Input File](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#id2) subsection for details.

Here's an example of an input file (with a single entry):

```
http://www.openclonk.org/header/logo.png
        out=openclonk.png
```

Answer (score 7):

Example:

make a textfile, **list.txt**, with links:

```
https://www.google.hu/search?q=a&start=0
https://www.google.hu/search?q=a&start=10
https://www.google.hu/search?q=a&start=20
```

command:

```
aria2c -i list.txt -j 2
```

where -j option specifies the number of parallel downloads.

Result:

```
    D:\aria2c>aria2c -ihtml.txt

12/22 07:49:57 [NOTICE] Downloading 3 item(s)

12/22 07:49:57 [WARN] aria2c had to connect to the other side using an unknown TLS protocol. The integrity and confidentiality of the connection might be compromised.
Peer: www.google.hu (2a00:1450:400d:805::2003:443)

12/22 07:49:57 [WARN] aria2c had to connect to the other side using an unknown TLS protocol. The integrity and confidentiality of the connection might be compromised.
Peer: www.google.hu (2a00:1450:400d:805::2003:443)

12/22 07:49:57 [WARN] aria2c had to connect to the other side using an unknown TLS protocol. The integrity and confidentiality of the connection might be compromised.
Peer: www.google.hu (2a00:1450:400d:805::2003:443)

12/22 07:49:57 [NOTICE] File already exists. Renamed to /cygdrive/d/aria2c/search.1.

12/22 07:49:57 [NOTICE] File already exists. Renamed to /cygdrive/d/aria2c/search.2.

12/22 07:49:58 [NOTICE] Download complete: /cygdrive/d/aria2c/search.2

12/22 07:49:58 [NOTICE] Download complete: /cygdrive/d/aria2c/search.1
[#c86c02 0B/0B CN:1 DL:77KiB]
12/22 07:49:58 [NOTICE] Download complete: /cygdrive/d/aria2c/search

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
efcadb|OK  |    46KiB/s|/cygdrive/d/aria2c/search.2
554614|OK  |    44KiB/s|/cygdrive/d/aria2c/search.1
c86c02|OK  |    60KiB/s|/cygdrive/d/aria2c/search

Status Legend:
(OK):download completed.
```

In the result, search will be the start=0 file and te search.2 will be the start=20 file, in order. So you can rename them in order, with an another script.

Solution:

Make a textfile, **list.txt**, with links, and after each link, started with tab or space the option:

```
https://www.google.hu/search?q=a&start=0
 out=s1.html
https://www.google.hu/search?q=a&start=10
 out=s2.html
https://www.google.hu/search?q=a&start=20
 out=s3.html
```

Command:

```
aria2c --input-file list.txt
```

Result:

```
D:\aria2c>aria2c --input-file list.txt

12/22 20:54:44 [NOTICE] Downloading 3 item(s)

12/22 20:54:45 [WARN] aria2c had to connect to the other side using an unknown TLS protocol. The integrity and confidentiality of the connection might be compromised.
Peer: www.google.hu (2a00:1450:400d:805::2003:443)

12/22 20:54:45 [WARN] aria2c had to connect to the other side using an unknown TLS protocol. The integrity and confidentiality of the connection might be compromised.
Peer: www.google.hu (2a00:1450:400d:805::2003:443)

12/22 20:54:45 [WARN] aria2c had to connect to the other side using an unknown TLS protocol. The integrity and confidentiality of the connection might be compromised.
Peer: www.google.hu (2a00:1450:400d:805::2003:443)
[DL:37KiB][#177d35 0B/0B][#bae5ee 0B/0B][#d1da5b 0B/0B]
12/22 20:54:46 [NOTICE] Download complete: /cygdrive/d/aria2c/s1.html
[DL:53KiB][#bae5ee 0B/0B][#d1da5b 0B/0B]
12/22 20:54:47 [NOTICE] Download complete: /cygdrive/d/aria2c/s2.html

12/22 20:54:47 [NOTICE] Download complete: /cygdrive/d/aria2c/s3.html

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
177d35|OK  |    53KiB/s|/cygdrive/d/aria2c/s1.html
bae5ee|OK  |    18KiB/s|/cygdrive/d/aria2c/s2.html
d1da5b|OK  |    15KiB/s|/cygdrive/d/aria2c/s3.html

Status Legend:
(OK):download completed.
```

[aria2c examples](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#example)

Comment: The question was about specifying a different filename for each url, and [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47483808/5420570) answers that while your not.

Comment: You have right, thank you for observation. Edited.