# How to download URLs in a csv and naming outputs based on a column value

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, download

### 1. OS: Linux / Ubuntu x86/x64

### 2. Task:

Write a Bash shell script to download URLs in a (large) csv (as fast/simultaneous as possible) and naming each output on a column value.

#### 2.1 Example Input:

A CSV file containing lines like:

```
001,http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5342/a.jpg
002,http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7413/b.jpg
003,http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3742/c.jpg
```

#### 2.2 Example outputs:

Files in a folder, `outputs`, containg files like:

```
001.jpg
002.jpg
003.jpg
```

### 3. My Try:

I tried mainly in two styles.

#### 1. Using the download tool's inner support

Take `ariasc` as an example, it support use `-i` option to import a file of URLs to download, and (I think) it will process it in parallel to max speed. It do have `--force-sequential` option to force download in the order of the lines,  but I failed to find a way to make the naming part happen.

#### 2. Splitting first

split the file into files and run a script like the following to process it:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=$1

while IFS=, read serino url
do 
    aria2c -c "$url" --dir=outputs --out="$serino.jpg"
done < "$INPUT"
```

However, it means for each line it will restart `aria2c` again which seems cost time and low the speed.
Though, one can run the script in bash command multiple times to get 'shell-level' parallelism, it seems not to be the best way.

Any suggestion ?
Thank you,

Comment: Reference : CURL should help you .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362402/save-file-to-specific-folder-with-curl-command

Comment: See also [Can aria2c download list of urls with specific file names for each](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46102806/6770384).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aria2c` supports so called *option lines* in input files. From `man aria2c`

> **-i, --input-file=**
>   Downloads  the  URIs  listed in FILE. You can specify multiple sources for a single entity by putting multiple URIs on a single line separated by  the  TAB  character. Additionally, **options can be specified after each URI line**. Option lines must start with one or more white space characters (SPACE or TAB) and must  only  contain  one option  per line.

and later on

> These options have exactly same meaning of the ones in the command-line  options,  **but it just  applies to the URIs it belongs to**.  Please note that for options in input file -- prefix must be stripped.

You can convert your csv file into an `aria2c` input file:

```
sed -E 's/([^,]*),(.*)/\2\n  out=\1/' file.csv | aria2c -i -
```

This will convert your file into the following format and run `aria2c` on it.

```
http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5342/a.jpg
  out=001
http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7413/b.jpg
  out=002
http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3742/c.jpg
  out=003
```

However this won't create files `001.jpg`, `002.jpg`, … but `001`, `002`, … since that's what you specified. Either specify file names with extensions or guess the extensions from the URLs.

If the extension is always jpg you can use

```
sed -E 's/([^,]*),(.*)/\2\n  out=\1.jpg/' file.csv | aria2c -i -
```

To extract extensions from the URLs use

```
sed -E 's/([^,]*),(.*)(\..*)/\2\3\n  out=\1\3/' file.csv | aria2c -i -
```

Warning: This works if and only if every URL ends with an extension. For instance, due to the missing extension the line `001,domain.tld/abc` would not be converted at all, causing `aria2c` to fail on the "URL" `001,domain.tld/abc`.

Comment: Given the actual download speed, this was selected as the ans. The actual number of images are 960k, so when I direct put the file containing the URLs, the aria2c will crash. One can use a bash command, named `split`, to split the file into small ones by lines. `split -l/5 $FILE`, for instance. Then process them one by one.

Comment: You've saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

Using all standard utilities you can do this to download in parallel:

```
tr '\n' ',' < file.csv |
xargs -P 0 -d , -n 2 bash -c 'curl -s "$2" -o "$1.jpg"' -
```

`-P 0` option in `xargs` lets it run commands in parallel (one per core processor)

Comment: If the CSV is large you want to limit the number of parallel tasks, though. You will simply congest your network if you run more than a few dozen at the same time.

Comment: I thought `-P 0` controls that. ˆt says in `man xargs` that `If max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible at a time`

Comment: That's how many the CPU will allow, but it will easily start more than your network can handle for a task that is I/O bound.

Comment: I have been using `xargs -P 0` to run `curl` command on input files containing 400k-500k records, never ran into any clogging issues.

Comment: The relationship is somewhat complex. 500 fetches with a fast network to a small number of sites with good connectivity will be fine; 500 fetches with a fast CPU to a large number of small sites with poor connectivity will congest your network.