# Get list of files from https and save as txt file

Tags: linux, wget, txt, lftp, aria2

I want to get list of directories from https for `aria2c`.

Since, as I know, unlikely to `wget`, there is no recurrent option in `aria2c`, I going to use the txt file as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102806/can-aria2c-download-list-of-urls-with-specific-file-names-for-each)

So I need the list of directories.

[This](https://physionet.org/files/mimic3wdb-matched/1.0/) is the target https.

I tried `lftp` but there were some cerificate errors.

It would be greatful to let me know how to get the txt file.
Thank you!

Comment: Try this: `curl https://physionet.org/files/mimic3wdb-matched/1.0/ | grep -o -P '(?<=">).*(?=/</a>)' | grep -v '\.\.'`

Comment: Thank you for answering!!. The command give me only  top-level (parental) directory (e.g /p00 , /p01 ...) what I want is all the filenames (e.g /p00/p000020/3544749_0001.dat ...) !!

Comment: Put it in a loop then, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hacked together script.

```bash
function list_folder() {
    echo "Starting new run! $1"
    content=$(curl -s -L 'https://physionet.org/files/mimic3wdb-matched/1.0/'"$1")
    folders=$(echo "$content" | grep -o -P '(?<=">).*(?=/</a>)' | grep -v '\.\.')
    # files are all the entries that don't end with a `/`
    files=$(echo "$content" | grep -o -P '(?<=">).*[^/](?=<\/a>)')
    echo "FOLDERS: $folders"
    echo "FILES: $files"
    for folder in $folders; do
        list_folder "$1/$folder"
    done
}

list_folder
```

It'll recursively search all the files in the directory listing and print them. If you want to save the files into a file, just redirect `$files` into the file.

You can also try making it multi threaded by appending a `&` to the `list_folder` calls.